# Gradle plugin Jasper jspc to precompile jsps

Tags: jsp, gradle, precompile, jasper-plugin

I'm using the [jassper jspc gradle plugin](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/reference/-/knowledge_base/7-0/jasper-jspc-gradle-plugin) I want to pre-compile all my jsps "on build", the configuration is as notice the documentation:

```
    buildscript {

        repositories {
            [...]
            maven {
                url "https://cdn.lfrs.sl/repository.liferay.com/nexus/content/groups/public"
            }
        }

        dependencies {
            [...]
"com.liferay.gradle.plugins.jasper.jspc", version: "2.0.1"
        }
    }
    [...]
    apply plugin: "com.liferay.jasper.jspc"
```

When I execute "gradle task" I can see the plugin tasks were created:

```
Verification tasks
------------------
check - Runs all checks.
compileJSP - Compile JSP files to check for errors.
test - Runs the unit tests.
```

But if I luch one of the tasks, for example gradle compileJSP I get the same error:

```
:project-web:generateJSPJava
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at com.liferay.jasper.jspc.JspC.main(JspC.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at com.liferay.jasper.jspc.JspC._runWithClassPath(JspC.java:168)
        at com.liferay.jasper.jspc.JspC.main(JspC.java:46)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.getExpressionFactory(JspUtil.java:1192)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspUtil.validateExpressions(JspUtil.java:654)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1366)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1142)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:859)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1502)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2347)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2353)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:499)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2297)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validate(Validator.java:1890)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:223)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:451)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.processFile(JspC.java:1178)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspC.execute(JspC.java:1345)
        ... 6 more
:project-web:generateJSPJava FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':project-web:generateJSPJava'.
> Process 'command '/home/[...]/.sdkman/candidates/java/8u121/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

Any idea or alternative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitively this plugin is not working anymore. In addition nobody is using it (check maven repo use)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the version of `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` you are using at runtime is different to the version of `javax.el.ExpressionFactory` that the `jasper.jspc` plugin was compiled against.

I've done a jar search [here](https://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|fc%3A%22javax.el.ExpressionFactory%22) on maven central for `javax.el.ExpressionFactory`. Perhaps you could use `gradle dependencyInsight` to see why the class version has changed.

If you want to see where the class is located you could add this to your build.

```
task printExpressionFactoryLocations {
    doLast {
        String findMe = 'javax/el/ExpressionFactory.class'
        def configuration = buildscript.configurations.classpath
        def jars = configuration.asFileTree.matching {
            include '*.jar'
        }
        jars.files.each { File jar ->
            def entries = zipTree(jar).matching {
               include findMe
            }
            if (!entries.files.empty) {
               println "Found $findMe in $jar.name"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply! I tried your code task and the result is: Found javax/el/ExpressionFactory.class in javax.el-api-2.2.4.jar
I'm not sure what I can do now with that! How can it help me dependecyInsight? Whats could I do if the problem is the version as you said? Thanks again!

Comment: I'm guessing you'll see `xxx:el-api:y.y.y -> 2.2.4` in the dependency insight where a later version has been chosen due to conflict resolution. I'm guessing you'll want to [force](https://docs.gradle.org/3.4.1/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolutionStrategy:force%28java.lang.Object[]%29) an earlier version of the dependency rather than letting version 2.2.4 "win".

Comment: Thanks! I've tried that you said me but it doesn't work: gradle -q dependencies el-api:dependencies
Do you know what I'm doing wrong? thanks again

Comment: I think it's `javax.el:javax.el-api` see [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.el/javax.el-api/2.2.4)

Comment: It doesn't work ... :-(
user@user-computer:~/projects/myProject$ gradle -q dependencies javax.el:javax.el-api:dependencies

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Project 'javax.el' not found in root project 'myProject'.